# Making a Digital clock with a specific time for Sony Vegas Platinum 12

Tags: video, vegas-pro

I'm using Vegas Platinum 12 and I want to create a time code in a video.  But here is the catch.  I want to start the clock at a specific time and have the count start at that time, i.e 05:21:34 or 21:01:19, etc...  Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

It is feasible in Vegas **Pro** using Vegasaur's [Text Wizard](http://vegasaur.com/text-generation-wizard), but your problem is that "Vegas Platinum 12" is not Vegas Pro, it is consumer-level Movie Studio Platinum 12.